# We are applying for Australia and my wife wants to pursue her diploma?

Tags: statement-of-purpose, australia

My wife and I want to go to Australia. She wants to pursue her diploma in hotel management and so we are on the verge of writing our SOP. Should I state that she is single or married, as we heard that there is a chance of cancellation of the visa if the diploma student is declared married?

Comment: You should never give false information on such a document. Governments are not tolerant of this and consequences can be serious. To give different decisions based on a woman's marital status would also probably be a violation of human rights in Australia and many other territories.

Comment: Thank you sir, but i mean to says that will married woman can get a student visa on Australia on Diploma in Hotel Management

Comment: Other than as a spouse, what is your role here? Why do you say "our SOP", not "her SOP"? An SOP is for an individual.

Comment: How will *you* go to Australia? Since only she is applying.

Comment: @quantum Dependents can also come [as part of the visa process](https://www.studyaustralia.gov.au/english/latest-travel-and-visa-advice/updates/step-by-step-guide-to-visa-and-entry-requirements).

Comment: Voting to close. From what I can tell, the question is "should I lie on my visa application?" When phrased like this, I hope the answer is obvious; moreover, we have no particular expertise to offer when it comes to visa-related issues.

Answer (score 4):

Tell the truth, it's that simple. It is not in any aspect more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell the truth, because if you don't, any visas issued can be cancelled. When you fill the visa application form, there'll usually be a box that goes "I declare that all information contained in this application are true to the best of my knowledge. I understand that false declaration may lead to consequences up to and including the cancellation of your visa". There is probably a similar box in the university's application form. You are supposed to tick it to say you understand.

If you lie about your marital status and are discovered, then you can expect some pretty severe legal consequences, and you can expect to be expelled from the university.